# What bonuses or handicaps does the AI opponent get in Brutal?

Tags: command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars

When playing Command and Conquer 3: Tiberium Wars on Skirmish and fighting the AI on Brutal (any type strategy pick), he destroys me. I'm not good, I acknowledge that, but he has built so much so quickly that it looks impossible to beat by normal resource accumulation.

Does the AI get a handicap+ or some sort of other bonus that I don't have? I can't record it to watch like AOE II Kings. I have looked at Intelligence power, but I couldn't see a whole lot that looked out of whack.

Comment: Handicap+ ?? Is that a part of the game? I've never heard that term before.

Comment: Funny enough while googling this term i came across this 50% handicap on brutal : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGb9IVs6ySc

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket No.  I'm saying it may be there for the AI just unknown.

Comment: Aha. We'll I don't know if the handicap is by default on brutal but I would assume so due to the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brutal AI gets double income.

You can see this in the manual

[image]

On the [wiki](http://cnc.wikia.com/wiki/Artificial_Intelligence_(Tiberium_Wars))

> **Brutal AI**, this type of AI is the most difficult AI, known to be equipped with a dreadful multi-tasking ability, it uses every advantage to build and continuously expand their base and strike forces. Almost every second is used to perform an action. Even when they assault your base, they still have the resources to expand their own base and build another strike forces. While you are trying to defend your base, they may strike another of your forward bases, try to split the concentration of your forces. Only a few commanders could survive against this highly-skilled AI, while others think "From where they could gain the resources to advance so fast?" **In fact, this AI gets double money as stated in the Kane's Wrath instruction manual.**

And supported by [other forum posts](https://forum.quartertothree.com/t/c-c-3-skirmish-difficulty-question/44070/2)

> According to the manual, the AI doesn't cheat except **on the Brutal
>    difficulty, where it gets double income**

Comment: Thanks!  What I get for not getting the book with the disc.